Move Video File from Azure Blob Storage to Sharepoint site in C#
Please give advice to move a zoom recording video file from Azure Blob Storage to Sharepoint directly using C#. Recently, the process that I created is to get the Azure storage file uri -> download the file at local device -> Upload the file to Sharepoint. However, now I want the Azure file to be uploaded directly to Sharepoint without needing to download the file to local storage first. How can I achieve that?


public async Task<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File> UploadFromUrl(string siteUrl, string root, string path, string filename, string originUrl)
{
    using ClientContext clientContext = authManager.GetContext(siteUrl);
    string text = _downloadDirectory + filename;
    Folder uploadDirectory = GetUploadDirectory(clientContext, root, path);
    //new WebClient().DownloadFile(new Uri(originUrl), text);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    GrantAccess(_downloadDirectory);
    await DownloadFileTaskAsync(client, new Uri(originUrl), text);

    long length = new FileInfo(text).Length;
    int num = 10485760;
    if (length <= num)
    {
        return UploadFromBuffer(clientContext, uploadDirectory, filename, text);
    }

    return new ChunkUploader(clientContext, num).Upload(uploadDirectory, text);
}



Recently, the process that I created is to get the Azure storage file uri -> download the file at local device -> Upload the file to Sharepoint. However, now I want the Azure file to be uploaded directly to Sharepoint without needing to download the file to local storage first. How can I achieve that?
Updated Progress:
I am trying to implement the method suggested below, as follows:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace ZoomRecordingHelper
{
    public class GraphHandler
    {
        public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        public GraphHandler()
        {
            var clientId = "";
            var clientSecret = "";
            var tenantId = "";

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        }

        public async Task UploadFileToSharePoint(string siteId, string driveId, string fileName, Stream fileStream)
        {
            try
            {
                var uploadUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items/root:/{fileName}:/content";

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                    using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uploadUrl))
                    {
                        httpRequest.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                        httpRequest.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                        using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest))
                        {
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            var clientId = "";
            var clientSecret = "";
            var tenantId = "";

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

            var accessTokenResult = await clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

            return accessTokenResult.Token;
        }
    }
}

However, there are errors in applying GraphServiceClient

cannot convert from Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential to Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProvider
cannot convert from string[] to Microsoft.Graph.IHttpProvider in line GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

Here is my .csproj file content:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="2.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="5.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.WebPubSub" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" Version="14.0.4762.1000" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM" Version="16.1.25012.12000" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nexus.Base.EventGridExtensions" Version="2020.3.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nexus.Base.EventHubExtensions" Version="2020.3.13.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="PnP.Framework" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="6.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="6.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="6.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="6.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="6.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Zoom.API.Client.Library" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Aside from that: you're asking for assistance, but haven't provided any specific issue. Please read [ask], and edit your question to provide a [mcve] with all relevant detail.


I want the Azure file to be uploaded directly to Sharepoint without needing to download the file to local storage first. How can I achieve that?

You can use the below code to upload a video file from Azure blob storage to share point without downloading to local drive using Azure .Net SDK.
First, create Microsoft Entra ID application and grant API permissions like below:
Portal:

Code:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace UserProperties
{
    public class GraphHandler
    {
        public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }

        public GraphHandler()
        {
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            var tenantId = "TenantID";

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
        }

        public async Task UploadFileToSharePoint(string siteId, string driveId, string fileName, Stream fileStream)
        {
            try
            {
                var uploadUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items/root:/{fileName}:/content";

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                    using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uploadUrl))
                    {
                        httpRequest.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                        httpRequest.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                        using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest))
                        {
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            var clientId = "ClientID";
            var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            var tenantId = "TenantID";

            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
            var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

            var accessTokenResult = await clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

            return accessTokenResult.Token;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Configuration
            var connectionString = "<your azure storage connection string>";
            var containerName = "your container name";
            var blobName = "earth.mp4";

            var handler = new GraphHandler();
            var siteId = "SiteID"; 
            var driveId = "DriveID"; 
            var fileName = "sample.mp4";

            var blobStream = await GetBlobStreamAsync(connectionString, containerName, blobName);
            await handler.UploadFileToSharePoint(siteId, driveId, fileName, blobStream);
        }

        public static async Task<Stream> GetBlobStreamAsync(string connectionString, string containerName, string blobName)
        {
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

            var response = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
            return response.Value.Content;
        }
    }
}

Output:
File uploaded successfully.

Reference:
.net core - How can I upload file and folder in SharePoint Document Library using Graph API in C#? - Stack Overflow by Rukmini.
My .csproj file:
Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.56.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


There are two errors when I was applying the method.

cannot convert from Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential to Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProvider
cannot convert from string[] to Microsoft.Graph.IHttpProvider
in line GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);


Edit yout question and add your detail error.

What are the Nuget packages are you using?

Remove the unwanted packages from the application.

I used https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json nugget package and two private packages from my company.

Please share you .csproj file.

I updated my .csproj file in answer.

I have shared my .csproj file in the question. Please check it out, thank you.

Try my packages which I used in answer.

Okay, the errors are gone. Thanks a lot!

Hi, sorry to bother you again. I have a problem when getting the blobStream. I have ensured that my containerName and blobName are correct. However, when I checked the existence of the blobClient using blobClient.ExistAsync(), it always returns false. Do you know why a blob file cannot be detected while it actually existed in the Azure Blob Storage? Thanks in advance.

Can you raise new question with brief explanation? and add error what you are getting in the question.

Paste the question link here.

can you open this link? I've just posted the question but it is still being under reviewed.
https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78846765
